# JetBrains IntelliJ Error launching Intellij Platform - Error invoking main method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have IntelliJ IDEA and other JetBrains products installed and they worked great (PyCharm, Android Studio, Clion, WebStorm) till today, now I just get opening message:

> Error launching Intellij Platform - Error invoking main method

I have installed:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25

and JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk.

I posted at: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5533036#5533036 and https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/459951

---

I installed (clean) Windows 8.1 and now it works, but there should be option to wipe all java configs from Windows to avoid such mess, cause this is not the solution.

Comment: Did you move your installations of IntelliJ IDEA and the other products to a directory with spaces in the path? This can cause such a problem.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains

Comment: Having the same issue. I was working with AS just fine and installled a new JDK to test with eclipse. AS still worked fine and suddenly I got a vague gradle error when running my program. Upon restarting AS i got `Error invoking main method`

Comment: I don't know if it helps; but similar IDE, Android Studio have a similar issue on windows and starting studio.exe instead of studio64.exe (ie 32bit exe) is a walkaround solution in this case, which has the same error when starting android studio, "Error invoking main method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meet this error today. Java update message jump out when I work with AndroidStudio. I accept it but my AS can't display res files after installation. I restart AS and see the error.
I guess new version java produce the error. The updated java part is jre,  version is 1.8.0_101, but jdk's version is still 1.8.0_92. So I download and install new version jdk(1.8.0_101, the same as jre).
AndroidStudio successfully starts now.
Maybe this solution can also work to IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

For people who couldn't solve it by having the same version of JDK and JRE.
Uninstall IntelliJ and also clean all the files that are not swept automatically by uninstalling. you can find them in C:\Users\Usuario\AppData on Local and LocalLow find the JetBrains folder and delete all the files related to IntelliJ.
Then proceed to reinstalling it. That solved it for me.