# Android Studio doesn't start: Error invoking main method

Tags: android, ide

My Android Studio suddenly stopped starting, jre and jdk are installed, neither the studio.exe or the studio64.exe do start, my system is 64 bit.

My JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 , it is real.

The only error I get when starting Android Studio is: Error invoking main method.

It worked before, about 1 month ago.

Still not working, I need the IDE really much

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000145/jetbrains-intellij-error-launching-intellij-platform-error-invoking-main-metho?answertab=active#tab-top It's intellij but it should work

Comment: Still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by reinstalling AndroidStudio, JRE and JDK.

Answer (score 2):

you are actually missing the `idea.properties` file under the `Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`

restore this file, or create the new file under bin and add the contents from
https://gist.github.com/denofevil/8cfb3b581016d8364772 .

Then save and reopen the Android studio!.

Happy Coding.