# Android Studio "Error Invoking Main Method"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with my Android Studio. I just installed it but it cannot start it just says "error invoking main method".
Is there a way around this problem without needing to reinstall the Android bundle?

My download file reads "android-studio-bundle-145.3537739-windows"

Comment: check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000145/jetbrains-intellij-error-launching-intellij-platform-error-invoking-main-metho?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Update or install latest JRE and JDK in your system then restart and  open android studio.It will be work.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of JRE (1.8.0_112) and JDK (1.8.0_112) then I unistalled the Android Studio before reinstalling it. Now the setup finishes just well in installation but when I run Android Studio as an administrator it just loads in the background for 5 seconds then stops loading and remain silent without any further activity.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 Pro