# why do showing "error invoking main method" While open android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I uninstalled and reinstalled android studio 3.3 and jdk many times.

The updated java part is jre, version is 1.8.0_101, but jdk's version is still 1.8.0_92. So I download and install new version jdk(1.8.0_101, the same as jre).

And set JAVA_HOME,path,ANDROID_HOME .while open android studio showing "Error invoking main method" why the error showing?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38605454/4948006

Comment: I already tried by install low version of jdk but not working...@AM

Comment: Could you update your question, adding that detail?